# Is it bad for SEO to have multipe identical links in a section?

Tags: seo, links

I have a venue listings website with restaurants and bars and have sections for "latest comments", "latest listings", "latest reviews".

If 10 users have just commented on the same bar, that bar would be listed 10 times in a row under "latest comments" pointing to the same url.

Should I worry about that? Am I not wasting link juice by repeating the same links?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this does not seem helpful to users. As far as link value, you are dividing he link value by the number of links to that page, however, since they are pointing to the same page, there is no real loss. Still, like I said, if I understand you correctly, I would be avoiding this from a user experience (UX) perspective. It would make sense to me to clean this up if you can.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, google only looks at the first link from the duplicate links on a single page, but what you may want to do, instead of having a resulting layout like this:

```
Comment 1 from bar: ThisBar (at http://example.com)

     blablablablabla

Comment 2 from bar: ThisBar (at http://example.com)

     yaddayaddayaddayaddayaddayadda

Comment 3 from bar: ThisBar (at http://example.com)

     bangbangbangbangbangbangbang
```

You are better to organize your comments in this fashion:

```
3 Comments from bar: ThisBar (at http://example.com)

     Comment 1 by john on mm-dd-yyyy:

     blablablablabla

     Comment 2 by jack on mm-dd-yyyy:

     yaddayaddayaddayaddayaddayadda

     Comment 3 by Mandy on mm-dd-yyyy:

     bangbangbangbangbangbangbang
```

My apologies for poor grammar but the point here is that I rearranged how the comments are displayed so that there is only one link to the bar instead of multiple duplicate links. This also prevents users from downloading extra bytes that were required to craft the additional links.

Answer (score 1):

Mike is correct that there may be better ways to organize your links from the perspective of users.  However, from a PageRank perspective, duplicate links are not an issue.   Google only passes PageRank to the first of the duplicated links.